# aws-sdk not deploying image to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, sharp

I am using `AWS Lambda` to resize images in node.js by using `aws-sdk` and`sharp`

Issue I face is that it read file successfully and also apply resize operations  but not put object after resize.

Even not giving any error also. I check cloud watch where everything is alright but image not place in resize folder.

It only create key folders but image not there

```
return Promise.all(_croppedFiles.map(_cropFile => {
            return  S3.putObject({
                Body: _cropFile.buffer,
                Bucket: dstBucket,
                ContentType: _cropFile.config.contentType,
                Key: dstKey
            }).promise()                        
        }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no extension in the keyname, which makes it to be just a name and treated as a folder. provide your keyname as **dstKey.jpeg** or whatever extension you want , and set your content type to **image/jpeg**

No matter what's the format of your input image , the output image will always be stored in "jpeg" format